# Multiple Web Security Config Classes Filter Invocation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a SecurityConfig class in my Spring boot 1.3.6 project which I apply a filter on HttpSecurity.

Something like below,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll())
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

    }

    private JWTConfig securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfig(tokenProvider);
    }   
}


public class JWTConfig extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    public JWTConfig(TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JWTFilter customFilter = new JWTFilter(tokenProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Now I have add a external dependency jar which has similar Filter registration in its own SecurityConfig.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health").antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(getTokenAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(getCorrelationIdFilter(), getTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();
    }

    private TokenAuthenticationFilter getTokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();

    }
}
```

I can see the SecurityConfig class of external jar first hits and register the Filters and then project's SecurityConfig get invoke and register JWTFilter, when application start. But after latter filter registration, when I inspect HttpSecurity filters field, it contains only the JWTFilter.

Can I have all filters register in same HttpSecurity filters after those filters register with different SecurityConfigs?

Comment: @dur Well the thing is if i want to move the filter adding code of external jar to my project, I have some many dependencies also need to autowired again in my project security config class. Those are not mentioned in sample code. So I was thinking of way to register filters for HttpSecurity, which add in both from my project and external library by using configure(HttpSecurity http)

Comment: Thanks @dur. Yer I want to keey both Config. So while looking at your answer also I think I have to move my filter registration in external library to my project and add it inside a another SecurityConfigurerAdapter as shown in youre answer. Looks like I have to inject the dependecies and other code need for that again here.